# Incorrect unit allocation size. error comes when Tuning the Database

Tags: sql-server-2012, optimization

Here I am Using the SQL IDERA tool for checking the Index and performance of the Database, then i found below error, can any one tell what is it talking about.

> Incorrect unit allocation size. Drive C: has a queue length average of
>   7.26. This drive is also responsible for writing the transaction logs sequentially and performing the read/write of SQL Server pages which
>   is typically random
>
> This results in latency currently measured at 0.0036ms as the head
>   moves between sequential transactional log writing and the random
>   Reading/Writing of SQL Server pages.  The unit allocation size has
>   been detected to be 4KB.  SQL Server works far more efficiently with
>   unit allocation sizes of 64KB and larger.
>
> Recommendation: It is recommended that for busy databases the
>   Transaction logs reside on a different physical drive than the data
>   files and that a unit allocation size of 64KB or larger be used.

Comment: What exactly in IDERA you are using? Is this Idera Diagnostic Manager? or one of their free available tools for performance checkup? let me know the name of idera product you are using

Comment: This is IDERA SQL Doctor. and i have the Free version of this.
i am using for checking the Performance of the server and thru this i fix index's and other things also.

Comment: Posted my answer below, please try and check if that fixes the cause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point:

> Incorrect unit allocation size. Drive C: has a queue length average of 7.26. This drive is also responsible for writing the transaction logs sequentially and performing the read/write of SQL Server pages which is typically random*

1. This indicates that some of the user databases are hosted on the C: Drive which as per the best practice should not be the case. It is preferred that mdf should be on a drive with its respective RAID level for higher reads medium writes, while LDF should be on a different drive apart from MDF. and per the error message it seems you're MDF and LDF reside on C drive:

So check for those DB's whose files are on C: drive and move them to their respective data drives, if you have any, if not then get them attached.

2. For allocation of unit size in SQL Server read  [This article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2119/partition-offset-and-allocation-unit-size-of-a-disk-for-sql-server/) it will help:

And also as recommended and mentioned above in point a , you should move the heavy DB's files to their physical drives like D and L as per you're naming convention on the servers.

Comment: Problem is my Files is on another server and the application on the another server , then my application is slow due to this the Allocation problem.I am thinking that due to this problem may be my application could be slow.

_**PLEASE TELL ME DUE TO THIS PROBLEM WHAT THINGS ARE ARISES IN MY APPLICATION.**_

Comment: No that should not be a problem, it is advisable that database and web/app server should be on different machines. In terms of Performance. 2 boxes = 2 times the CPU, 2 times the RAM, and 2 times the spindles for disk access.

Comment: Ican't Understand this plz sir can u explain in wide...
**_2 boxes = 2 times the CPU, 2 times the RAM, and 2 times the spindles for disk access._**

Comment: Well that means better performance:: if same server both database and application is hosted on, would be loaded with CPU consumption and RAM consumption, so its better to have two different rather than everything getting loaded on one.

Comment: Also per security reasons: Well the first obvious advantage is that if someone breaks the box that houses your application server, they are not guaranteed access to the same server that houses the database. Also, by separating this functionality you make it easier on the IT (software devs, admins, etc) to minimize code change impact / policy updates on different aspects of the environment. This does not in any way fix poor coding or weak security (SQL injection, default username/passwords). but it does facilitate a better security posture overall.

Comment: @user38790, did you got this fixed!\?